# ImportError: cannot import name 'interval_pb2' from 'google.type'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy my code on cloud run which uses `google-cloud-aiplatform` library. After successful deployment, when I trigger the cloud run, it tries to import vertexai, which results in error as follows-

```
File "/app/main.py", line 16, in <module>  
  import vertexai  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/vertexai/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>  
  from google.cloud.aiplatform import init  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>  
  from google.cloud.aiplatform import initializer  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/initializer.py", line 31, in <module>  
  from google.cloud.aiplatform import compat  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/compat/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>  
  from google.cloud.aiplatform.compat import services  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform/compat/services/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>  
  from google.cloud.aiplatform_v1beta1.services.dataset_service import (  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>  
  from .services.dataset_service import DatasetServiceClient  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/services/dataset_service/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>  
  from .client import DatasetServiceClient  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/services/dataset_service/client.py", line 51, in <module>  
  from google.cloud.aiplatform_v1beta1.services.dataset_service import pagers  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/services/dataset_service/pagers.py", line 27, in <module>  
  from google.cloud.aiplatform_v1beta1.types import annotation  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/types/__init__.py", line 196, in <module>  
  from .featurestore_service import (  
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1beta1/types/featurestore_service.py", line 32, in <module>  
  from google.type import interval_pb2  # type: ignore  
ImportError: cannot import name 'interval_pb2' from 'google.type' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/type/__init__.py)"
```

My library version is google-cloud-aiplatform>=1.20 and python version is 3.10. Can anyone please let me know how to make it work?

This is my requirements file-

```
google-api-core==1.32.0   
google-api-core[grpc]  
google-cloud-aiplatform>=1.20  
google-cloud-bigquery  
google-cloud-core==1.7.2  
google-cloud-logging==2.7.0  
googleapis-common-protos==1.52.0  
grpcio==1.39.0  
protobuf>=3.19
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not using the latest versions of the library. That could be the reason.

It's possible that the newer version of libraries includes improvements or bug fixes related to GCP integration. So upgrading versions resolve these kinds of issues.

Here are the latest versions

```
google-api-core==2.11.1 
google-cloud-aiplatform==1.28.1   
google-cloud-core==2.3.3  
google-cloud-logging==3.6.0  
googleapis-common-protos==1.59.1  
grpcio==1.56.2
protobuf=4.23.4
```

Comment: I have already tried the latest version of `google-cloud-aiplatform` as well, same error.

Comment: @AnkitSeth Can you share minimal reproducible steps?

Comment: Create a virtual environment (python 3.10) and install the above mentioned libraries. Then run the following line - `import vertexai`.

Comment: @AnkitSeth Can you also share the `dockerfile` which you deployed on cloud run ?A

Comment: The dockerfile content is almost same as what is given here - https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service. The only difference is that python version is 3.10 and I have an extra line `COPY requirements.txt ./` after the 'ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True' line.

Comment: @AnkitSeth, I tried to recreate your issue. I didn't get any errors like yours. Can you confirm that your project is running successfully on your local machine? if possible, can you share your python file.

Comment: I tried all the latest versions, this error is gone but a new error came. When I try to do `import google.cloud.logging`, it shows error and tells to downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.

Comment: @AnkitSeth can you share your complete error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254746/discussion-between-ankit-seth-and-roopa-m).

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved the issue by uninstalling all the python libraries from my virtual environment and then installing them by not giving the specific versions. Gave version only for the library which I needed to have specifically. `pip` took care of the compatible versions. Following is the requirements file I used to install-

> Flask
> Flask-CSV
> google-api-core
> google-auth
> google-cloud-aiplatform==1.28.0
> google-cloud-audit-log
> google-cloud-bigquery
> google-cloud-core
> google-cloud-datastore
> google-cloud-logging
> google-cloud-runtimeconfig
> google-cloud-storage
> google-cloud-workflows
> googleapis-common-protos
> grpcio
> grpcio-status
> numpy
> pandas
> protobuf
> requests

Then I ran `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt`.
I was able to install all the libraries and do all the imports successfully.